# Linking text feature names to their tfidf value

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-processing, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn to extract text features from a "bag of words" text (text tokenized on single words).
To do so, I'm using a [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) to also reduce the weight of very frequent words (ie: "a", "the", etc).

```
text = 'Some text, with a lot of words...'
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    min_df=1,  # min count for relevant vocabulary
    max_features=4000,  # maximum number of features
    strip_accents='unicode',  # replace all accented unicode char
    # by their corresponding  ASCII char
    analyzer='word',  # features made of words
    token_pattern=r'\w{4,}',  # tokenize only words of 4+ chars
    ngram_range=(1, 1),  # features made of a single tokens
    use_idf=True,  # enable inverse-document-frequency reweighting
    smooth_idf=True,  # prevents zero division for unseen words
    sublinear_tf=False)

# vectorize and re-weight
desc_vect = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform([text])
```

I would now like to be able to link each predicted feature with its corresponding `tfidf` float value, storing it in a dict

```
{'feature1:' tfidf1, 'feature2': tfidf2, ...}
```

I achieved it by using

```
d = dict(zip(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), desc_vect.data))
```

I would like to know if there was a better, scikit-learn native way to do such a thing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single document, this should be fine. An alternative, that works when the document set is small, is [this recipe of mine](https://gist.github.com/larsmans/3745866) that uses [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

If you want to do this for multiple documents, then you can adapt the code in [`DictVectorizer.inverse_transform`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py#L126):

```
desc_vect = desc_vect.tocsr()

n_docs = desc_vect.shape[0]
tfidftables = [{} for _ in xrange(n_docs)]
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

for i, j in zip(*desc_vect.nonzero()):
    tfidftables[i][terms[j]] = X[i, j]
```